# Python AWS Boto3: How to read files from S3 bucket?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Using Boto3, the python script downloads files from an S3 bucket to read them and write the contents of the downloaded files to a file called `blank_file.txt`.

My question is, how would it work the same way once the script gets on an AWS Lambda function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lambda provides 512 MB of **`/tmp`** space. You can use that mount point to store the downloaded S3 files or to create new ones.

```
s3client.download_file(bucket_name, obj.key, '/tmp/'+filename)
...
blank_file = open('/tmp/blank_file.txt', 'w')
```

The working directory used by Lambda is `/var/task` and it is a read-only filesystem. You will not be able to create files in it.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda functions get 500MB of temporary space in "/tmp" available for temporary storage while your function executes.

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/