# Uploading file to AWS S3 through Chalice API call

Tags: python, python-3.x, boto3, chalice

I'm trying to upload a file to my S3 bucket through Chalice (I'm playing around with it currently, still new to this). However, I can't seem to get it right.

I have AWS setup correctly, doing the tutorial successfully returns me some messages. Then I try to do some upload/download, and problem shows up.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name=<some region name, in this case oregon>)
BUCKET= 'mybucket'
UPLOAD_FOLDER = os.path.abspath('')  # the file I wanna upload is in the same folder as my app.py, so I simply get the current folder name

@app.route('/upload/{file_name}', methods=['PUT'])
def upload_to_s3(file_name):
    s3.meta.client.upload_file(UPLOAD_FOLDER+file_name, BUCKET, file_name)
    return Response(message='upload successful',
                    status_code=200,
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}
    )
```

Please don't worry about how I set my file path, unless that's the issue, of course.

I got the error log:

> No such file or directory: ''

in this case `file_name` is just `mypic.jpg`.

I'm wondering why the `UPLOAD_FOLDER` part is not being picked up. Also, for the reference, it seems like using absolute path will be troublesome with Chalice (while testing, I've seen the code being moved to `/var/task/`)

Does anyone know how to set it up correctly?

EDIT:

the complete script

```
from chalice import Chalice, Response

import boto3

app = Chalice(app_name='helloworld')  # I'm just modifying the script I used for the tutorial 
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name='us-west-2')
BUCKET = 'chalicetest1'

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return {'status_code': 200,
            'message': 'welcome to test API'}

@app.route('/upload/{file_name}, methods=['PUT'], content_types=['application/octet-stream'])
def upload_to_s3(file_name):
    try:
        body = app.current_request.raw_body
        temp_file = '/tmp/' + file_name
        with open(temp_file, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(body)
        s3.upload_file(temp_file, BUCKET, file_name)
        return Response(message='upload successful',
                        headers=['Content-Type': 'text/plain'],
                        status_code=200)
    except Exception, e:
        app.log.error('error occurred during upload %s' % e)
        return Response(message='upload failed',
                        headers=['Content-Type': 'text/plain'],
                        status_code=400)
```

Comment: Which file from where do you want to upload to what location? You `app.py` is deployed to AWS API and Lambda functions, i.e. "same folder" probably is not true after it is deployed.

Comment: The file is in the same folder as the app.py. I also tried using absolute path for the file, neither works. I guess the correct question should be "what is the correct way of doing it?"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I got it running and this works for me as `app.py` in an [AWS Chalice project](https://github.com/aws/chalice):

```
from chalice import Chalice, Response
import boto3

app = Chalice(app_name='helloworld')

BUCKET = 'mybucket'  # bucket name
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')


@app.route('/upload/{file_name}', methods=['PUT'],
           content_types=['application/octet-stream'])
def upload_to_s3(file_name):

    # get raw body of PUT request
    body = app.current_request.raw_body

    # write body to tmp file
    tmp_file_name = '/tmp/' + file_name
    with open(tmp_file_name, 'wb') as tmp_file:
        tmp_file.write(body)

    # upload tmp file to s3 bucket
    s3_client.upload_file(tmp_file_name, BUCKET, file_name)

    return Response(body='upload successful: {}'.format(file_name),
                    status_code=200,
                    headers={'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
```

You can test this with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) and its [`--upload-file`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T) directly from the command line with:

```
curl -X PUT https://YOUR_API_URL_HERE/upload/mypic.jpg --upload-file mypic.jpg --header "Content-Type:application/octet-stream"
```

To get this running, you have to **manually attach the policy to write to s3** to the role of your lambda function. This role is auto-generated by Chalice. [Attach the policy (e.g. `AmazonS3FullAccess`) manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTL2h.png) next to the existing policy in the [AWS IAM web interface](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/roles) to the role created by your Chalice project.

Things to mention:

- You cannot write to the working directory `/var/task/` of the Lambda functions, but you have some space at `/tmp/`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43731162/5276734).
- You have to specify the accepted content-type `'application/octet-stream'` for the `@app.route` (and upload the file accordingly via `curl`).
- HTTP PUT puts a file or resource at a specific URI, so to use PUT this file has to be uploaded to the API via HTTP.

Comment: I'm still getting an 500 following your steps. I've created permission for the chalice user to have full access of S3, following this guy's instruction: http://brianpark.ca/blog/how_to_grant_access_to_s3_bucket_using_iam_policy/      I put in a try/except clause to log any error with `app.log.error(blhblah)` and nothing is being logged.

Comment: I attached the policy in AWS IAM web interface -> Roles -> helloworld-dev -> "Attach policy". Is your bucket name correct?

Comment: And this runs as Python 3.6 lambda function

Comment: yes the bucket name is correct. Also I'm running 2.7, but I don't think there's any difference in terms of code in this case?

Comment: Really strange. I tested it at my place again (in a new Chalice project with the code above) and it worked. Are you using the same `curl` command as mentioned above?

Comment: Yea, I tried your command and I also tried using httpie, both return 500. Usually for internal server error, there's something wrong with code. I was reexaming my other part of code, and it just doesn't seem like there's something going wrong. I'll add other part of script in EDIT

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting somewhere. I updated the policies on IAM console directly and every time I redeploy, the policy gets reset. I tried modifying in .chalice/police-dev.json as well, but when I redeploy, it informs me that it's going to remove those two statements I added

Comment: I'm selecting your answer as the correct answer as I think my issue comes from some other parts. I believe your solution solves the question I asked. I just have to figure out the permission part. If you have some take on that, please share with me :)

Comment: Thx. This is a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/94qIi4F) of my IAM settings, if that hepls. I added the s3 access via "Attach policy"

Comment: ah.....I see what you mean. I was editing the chalice role's (in your case, the hello-chalice-dev) permissions directly

Comment: This way (as in the picture) it is not overwritten after a `chalice deploy`.